# Add touchmove event listener on component mount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have component, where I tried to do next thing:

```
  disableBackgroundScroll() {
    const container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')

    container.addEventListener('touchmove', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
    }, false)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.disableBackgroundScroll()
  }
```

But I got an error:

> container.addEventListener is not a function

Why I can't add event listener on component mount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `getElementsByClassName` that you're using returns an array. You can read more about that here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

You can't call `addEventListener` on an array which is why it fails. You should either get the element you want from the resulting array or use something like `getElementById` instead.